# $\limsup$ of functions and sequential $\limsup$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f:(0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, a continous and non negative function and $g:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ a non negativa continuous function, if for all sequence $(t_n)$ such that $t_n\to +\infty$
$$\limsup_{n \to +\infty}f(t_n) \leq \int_0^1g(s)\limsup_{n\to \infty} f(t_ns)ds$$
can we conclude that
$$\limsup_{t \to +\infty}f(t) \leq \int_0^1g(s)\limsup_{t\to +\infty} f(t)ds?$$
If no, can we add some more condition for this to happen? Sorry for the lack of data, but I didn't find any reference that dealt with upper limit of functions at infinity.

Comment: Yes, because $\limsup_{n\to \infty} f(t_ns) \leq \limsup_{t\to \infty} f(t)$ for every $s>0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm: I don't see how that helps?

Comment: @joriki Isn't $\limsup_{t\to \infty} f(t)$ equal to $\limsup_{n\to \infty} f(t_n)$ for some sequence $t_n \to \infty$?

Comment: @geetha290krm: Ah, yes, that's nice, thank you.

Comment: @geetha290krm i don't know this result of sequence, do you have some reference?

Comment: @JarbasDantasSilva $(t_n s)$ is also a sequence tending to $\infty$.

Comment: @geetha290krm not this, the result that you used  to the left side of the inequality. Why can we conclude that if $\limsup_{n} f(t_n)\leq L$ for all sequence with these conditions then $\limsup_{t\to \infty}f(t)\leq L$? I know that is intuitive but i can't formalize.

Comment: What does $\lim \sup f(t) >L$ give you using the definition?